# jni.h: No such file or directory, path is included

Tags: c, gcc, java-native-interface, wrapper

I am trying to build a wrapper that I created using SWIG. When I try to build the file I get an error saying that jni.h is not found. I have the correct path to it specified with the -I flag but it still cannot find it. I am building on windows using cygwin. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ gcc -c zinnia_wrap.c -I "/C/Program Files \( x86\)/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/include"
-I "/C/Program Files \(x86\)/Java/jdk.1.6.0_23/include/win32"
zinnia_wrap.c:135:17: jni.h: No such file or directory
zinnia_wrap.c:159: error: parse error before '*' token
zinnia_wrap.c: In function `SWIG_JavaThrowException':
zinnia_wrap.c:160: error: `jclass' undeclared (first use in this function)
zinnia_wrap.c:160: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
zinnia_wrap.c:160: error: for each function it appears in.)
zinnia_wrap.c:160: error: parse error before "excep"
zinnia_wrap.c:175: error: `code' undeclared (first use in this function)
zinnia_wrap.c:178: error: `jenv' undeclared (first use in this function)
zinnia_wrap.c:179: error: `excep' undeclared (first use in this function)
zinnia_wrap.c:181: error: `msg' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: Did you mean /cygdrive/c/

Comment: @krsteeve - I tried adding /cygdrive/ to the front of my includes and it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured out what was wrong. In addition to adding /cygdrive/ to the front of the path (thanks @krsteeve) I needed to change "/Program Files \(x86\)/" to "/Program Files (x86)/". The first time I tried it out without the '\' it complained at me but now it is working. The full working command is as follows:

```
$ gcc -c zinnia_wrap.c -I "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/include" 
-I "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/include/win32"
```